# Get selected json value by key using jQuery and jsonp (vimeo api)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, vimeo-api

Let's say I have the following json result from an api:

```
{
  id: 116213129,
  title: "“An Episode,” by Palaxy Tracks",
  description: "Music: Palaxy Tracks<br /> Animation: Luca Tóth and Stephen McNally",
  url: "http://vimeo.com/116213129",
  thumbnail_small: "http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/502490003_100x75.jpg",
  thumbnail_medium: "http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/502490003_200x150.jpg",
  thumbnail_large: "http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/502490003_640.jpg",
  user_id: 14252792,
  width: 1920,
  height: 1080,
  tags: "palaxy tracks, music, an episode, animation, music video"
}
```

Now let's say I have some jQuery code and I want to only retrieve title and url, but nothing else and do something with them like push them into the value of a textbox on my page or a hidden input. I have seen the $.each method that loops through them, but I don't wt to do that. I just want a few values and I want to get them by their key.

Here is the sample jQuery code that loops through them, I got from jQuery API docs. How can I modify to just get those specific values?

```
<script>
  $.getJSON("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/116213129.json?jsoncallback=?", function (result) {
    var title = result.title;
    var description = result.description;
    $("#popVals").click(function () {
      $('#Video_Title').val(title);
      $('#Video_Description').val(description);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If you know the fields you want, just grab them; `result.id` or `result.title` or whatever.

Comment: Pointy is correct, but also: the "json result" in your question is actually a Javascript object, not JSON. That is what the callback returns to you in the `result` variable.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
http://player.vimeo.com/video/59179330 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: Just a heads up, this API is deprecated and will be shut down at some point in the future. You should be using the new API (developer.vimeo.com/api) which has proper support for CORS headers.

Comment: ok , lemme switch gears here and try that. I will modify the question if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the JQuery.getJSON [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

> The success callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a
>   JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed
>   using the $.parseJSON() method. It is also passed the text status of
>   the response.

In your case its a Javascript object which will be accessible via property access

```
<script>
  $.getJSON("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/116213129.json?jsoncallback=?", function (result) {
    var title = result.title;
    var url = result.url;
    //do something

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, I had just found something about result and using dot notation,  Let me see if I can get this working real quick. I assumed it was something simple, but I couldn't find many examples that were not using .each to loop through the entire result set.

Comment: As the docs that sunrize920 referenced say, `result` could be a "Javascript object **or array**," depending on the data returned. If it is an array, then it might make sense to use `each`, in which case a Javascript object would get passed to the `each` callback. However, the `result` for the resource you're requesting (a single video) is a single Javascript object.

Comment: I just updated my example. I am using a button with an id of "popVals" and upon click trying to populate two text input fields. Does that code look ok, because it isn't working for me.